# regex to find 4th comma from the end of line

Tags: regex, pattern-matching, matching, duplicates

I need a regular expression to match the forth comma from the end of the line, my line end in a comma.

For example, I'd like to select the comma after the G in the line below:

```
A,B,C,D,E,F,G,H,I,J,
```

Answer (score 6):

You can do this using a lookahead:

```
,(?=(?:[^,]*,){3}[^,]*$)
```

See it working online: [Rubular](http://rubular.com/r/Ib5mPpbzZV)

Answer (score 0):

You can use a quantifier and then backtrack:

Single-line input version (No newlines)

```
/.*\K,(?=(?:[^,]+,){3})/
```

Single-line matching version: (Newlines present)

```
/.*\K,(?=(?:[^,\n]+,){3})/
```

Multi-line matching version:

```
/.*\K,(?=(?:[^,]+,){3})/s
```